# Elect second column from grouped dataframe which is not in groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I wrote this code from grouping by column:

```
df[["Access code", "Points"]].groupby("Access code").sum()
```

And got two column dataframe:

```
Access code    Points
1               33
2               12
3               9
```

When i try to select second column from this datafram:

```
df[["Access code", "Points"]].groupby("Access code").sum()["Points""]
```

It doesn't work. How to do that?

Comment: `df[["Access code", "Points"]].groupby("Access code").sum().reset_index()["Points""] `

Comment: You can add the `as_index=False` parameter to your code : ``df[["Access code", "Points"]].groupby("Access code", as_index=False).sum()["Points"]``